# Default MVC web app has no ReturnUrl

Tags: url, asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication

When implementing an MVC web app with FormsAuthentication, it would appear that the FormsAuthentication mechanism automagically appends ?ReturnUrl=/ to your mvc routes. I did notice, though, that the default web application which MVC 3 provides out of the box implements FormsAuthentication but does not appear to suffer from the appended ReturnUrl=/ problem. I've looked through the code and can't see where this is being handled. Anyone know?

Comment: I've got the exact same problem and am stumped. Hopefully someone knows whats wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In the `LogOn` action of the `AccountController`, you'll see that if a return url is present, the user will be redirected to it after a successful log on:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (MembershipService.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
        {
            FormsService.SignIn(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: I don't think I explained my question fully. The issue is that the default web app DOES NOT append the ?ReturnUrl=/ . I'm implementing the code above which does work (although it raises another issue after logout and you want to log back in again). In fact, it doesn't append ANY return urls, no matter which page you go to.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the [Authorize] attribute to the Action or controller. This will generate the url needed to redirect after login.